# Production issue with random layouts and before_filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, nginx, before-filter

I have a crazy problem that is ONLY happening in production.  I cannot duplicate it in development at all.

For various reasons I have the following setup:

```
class OrdersController < PublicController
class PublicController < CommonController
class CommonController < ApplicationController
```

Inside of the CommonController I have a method like this:

```
def mobile_ready
 # set request format
  if mobile_view?
    request.format = :mobil      
    self.class.layout 'apps/dmvcs' 
  else 
    request.format = :html
  end 
end
```

Now here is where things get weird:

In OrdersController I have this:

```
before_filter :mobile_ready
```

and in PublicController I have this:

```
layout :select_layout

protected 

def select_layout
    mobile_view? ? 'public_mobile' : 'public'
end
```

I've traced the order of the calls and the mobile_ready method is called before select_layout, as I believe it should be.

But what is INCREDIBLY ODD is that the orders page IS NOT rendering with the public layout in the above exam!!??  It's rendering with the 'app/dmvcs' layout (WTF!?).  I've checked and triple checked and mobile_view? is FALSE on the desktop but it's still using the wrong layout.

What gets WEIRDER is if I have this:

```
class PublicController < CommonController
  layout 'public' # set this so there is a default layout
  layout :select_layout
```

It works 70% of the time, meaning it might render the correct layout or it might not!?

Has ANYONE seen anything like this before?  It clearly seems like some kind of odd caching or nginx issue, but I have no idea what to do here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts and I'm not 100% I have the correct solution but long story short I removed

```
     self.class.layout 'apps/dmvcs'
```

from the CommonController as I read about some thread safety issues and then I changed the `select_layout` method in PublicController to this:

```
def select_layout
 if mobile_view?
   if request.format == :mobile
     'apps/dmvcs' 
   else
     'public_mobile'
   end
 else
   'public'
 end
end
```

And it all *appears* to be working now.  Ill have to keep monitoring but that was annoying as heck.  Hope this helps someone else avoid setting a layout in a before_filter unless they want to deal with Rails caching/thread issues!